# Controller not defined laravel

Tags: html, laravel, routes

the error :

> Action App\Http\Controllers\formController@form not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ucar3\resources\views\layouts\Form.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ucar3\resources\views\layouts\Form.blade.php)

I tried changing the route in web.php

**web.php**

```
Route::resource('Inscription','inscriController');
```

**Controller**

```php
class FormController extends Controller
{   
    public function show() 
    {
        return view('pages.Inscription');
    }

    public function insert(Request $request)
    {
        $Cin = $request->input('Cin');
        $nom = $request->input('nom');
        $prenom = $request->input('prenom');
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $telephone = $request->input('telephone');
        $specialite = $request->input('specialite');
        $typedediplome = $request->input('typedediplome');
        $mentiondiplome = $request->input('mentiondiplome');
        $redoublement = $request->input('redoublement');
        $communication = $request->input('communication');
        $publication = $request->input('publication');
        $experiencePedagogiqueSecondaire = $request
            ->input('experiencePedagogiqueSecondaire');
        $experiencePedagogiqueSupérieur = $request 
            ->input('experiencePedagogiqueSupérieur');

        $data = array(['Cin'=>$Cin,
            'nom'=>$nom,
            'prenom'=>$prenom,
            'email'=>$email,
            'telephone'=>$telephone,
            'specialite'=>$specialite,
            'typedediplome'=>$typedediplome,
            'mentiondiplome'=>$mentiondiplome,
            'redoublement'=>$redoublement,
            'communication'=>$communication,
            'publication'=>$publication,
            'experiencePedagogiqueSecondaire'=>$experiencePedagogiqueSecondaire,
            'experiencePedagogiqueSupérieur'=>$experiencePedagogiqueSupérieur
        ]);

        DB::table('users')->insert($data);
        return view('pages.success');  
    }     
}
```

**Model**

```php
class form extends Model
{
    public $table = "form";
    protected $fillable = [
        'Cin',
        'nom',
        'prenom',
        'telephone',
        'email',
        'specialite',
        'typedediplome',
        'mentiondiplome',
        'redoublement',
        'communication',
        'publication',
        'experiencePedagogiqueSecondaire',
        'experiencePedagogiqueSupérieur'
    ];

    public $timestamps = true;
}
```

Comment: Class names should always be kept uppercase, and you can also use Eloquent to insert data in a more efficient way.

Comment: also you might wanna check your form action in your blade,

Answer (score 1):

As the Error says

```
formController@form not defined.
```

but in your class you've

```
FormController extends Controller
```

Please check if you are calling FormController with lower case 'F'.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have problems with your inscriController and your routes, use the following code:

web.php

```
use App\Http\Controllers\inscriController;
Route::resource('Inscription', inscriController::class);
```

app/Http/Controllers.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class inscriController extends Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you set the correct namespace in the FormController.php

You are also missing a function form inside your FormController.